# MySQL 8 Fails to Start Using systemctl On systemd Centos 9

Tags: mysql

i have installed mysql-community-server in my centos 9 machine, its service is not starting and giving me error while starting the service due to that i am unable to run mysql_secure_installation script as well

I check the status of mysqld.service. systemctl status mysqld.service -l

```
× mysqld.service - MySQL 8.0 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2023-04-16 16:05:08 WIB; 3min 44s ago
    Process: 175360 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-check-socket (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 175382 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-prepare-db-dir mysqld.service (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Process: 175453 ExecStopPost=/usr/libexec/mysql-wait-stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 302ms

Apr 16 16:05:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Apr 16 16:05:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL 8.0 database server.
Apr 16 16:05:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 16 16:05:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 16 16:05:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL 8.0 database server.
```

i check the status journalctl -xeu mysqld.service

```
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit mysqld.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
░░
░░ A stop job for unit mysqld.service has finished.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 2522 and the job result is done.
Apr 16 16:05:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 16 16:05:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
░░
░░ The unit mysqld.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 16 16:05:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL 8.0 database server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mysqld.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit mysqld.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 2522 and the job result is failed.
```

i check /var/log/mysqld.log

```
2023-04-16T07:09:36.513801Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32) starting as process 3184883
2023-04-16T07:09:36.521011Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2023-04-16T07:09:36.521100Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-04-16T07:09:36.546249Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012224] [InnoDB] Tablespace flags are invalid in datafile: ./ibdata1, Space ID:0, Flags: 21. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2023-04-16T07:09:36.546323Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012237] [InnoDB] Corrupted page [page id: space=0, page number=0] of datafile './ibdata1' could not be found in the doublewrite buffer.
2023-04-16T07:09:36.546341Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2023-04-16T07:09:37.045862Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
2023-04-16T07:09:37.046219Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-04-16T07:09:37.046306Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-04-16T07:09:37.047051Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.32)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

What can I do to solve the problem?

What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: The errors in your mysqld.log report tablespace corruption in `ibdata1`. This probably means you need to restore from the most recent backup. You could try InnoDB data recovery as documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html But I doubt that will work.

Comment: Anyway, this is not a code question, so I'm voting to move it to dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

The flags value of 21 corresponds to a MariaDB innodb flags.

MySQL has a SDI flag set at bit 14 which makes its flag look like 0x4800 (or other number differences depending on page size).

So the directory has been initialized with MariaDB and MySQL doesn't recognise it.

You could continue to use MariaDB there if you have data there or alternately back up the datadir and reinitialize it.

MariaDB would give a friendly descriptive error if it started on a MySQL directory ([MDEV-27882](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27882)).